# A Suzuki GZ125 marauder that won't power on at all

Tags: motorcycle, power, suzuki

I've been having a problem with my bike. I went to go to work in the morning and it turned on ok. Left to run for a few minutes then cut out. It turned over again and same thing ... I tried a third time and nothing what so ever: no power; lights completely dead ... I left it and went to work. The day after I tried again and still the same. I took battery off and checked the charge was reading good, so put it back and checked fuses. They looked ok, but I changed them anyways. It was still the same. Now I am looking at my starter motor, but saying *would the power be completely off if the starter motor was at fault*?
Any one have any ideas please....

Comment: Have you checked if your ignition lock? If its broken it could act as if you don't turn your key at all

Comment: Hi......no haven't but will have a look tomorrow ...will let you know....thanks mate

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: Two things to check. Fuse box, and kill switch. Of the two, a blown main fuse is the most likely to kill all electrical. If it has blown, find out why before replacing it.

Answer (score 2):

The starter motor has it's own completely different circuit on almost all vehicles, including yours.

The starter motor having an electrical issue would typically be isolated to that circuit.

Your issue must lay somewhere else in the electrical system.

I would first check these items.

- Main fuse.  Use a multimeter and don't use visual inspection.  Check the resistance of it and should be zero.
- Check power to your ignition switch.  If you have power to the switch but no power leaving the switch then this is probably your culprit.